# What are the existent Sentiment Analysis Algorithm?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I and a group of people are developing a Sentiment Analysis Algorithm. I would like to know what are the existent ones, because I want to compare them. Is there any article that have the main algorithms in this area?

Thanks in advance

Thiago

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question involves a discussion on algorithms on sentiment analysis and is not strictly related to programming/coding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of the papers on sentiment analysis may help you -

1. One of the earlier works by Bo Pang, Lillian Lee http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2002/EMNLP/pdfs/EMNLP219.pdf
2. A comprehensive survey of sentiment analysis techniques http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~pb/cs626-449-2009/prev-years-other-things-nlp/sentiment-analysis-opinion-mining-pang-lee-omsa-published.pdf
3. Study by Hang Cui, V Mittal, M Datar using 6-grams http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.5942&rep=rep1&type=pdf

For quick implementation naive bayes is recommended. You can find an example here http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/

We did a statistical comparision of various classifiers and found SVM to be most accurate, though for a dataset consisting of large contents 
( http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/ ) none of the methods worked well.Our study may not be accurate though. Also instead of treating sentiment analysis as a text classification problem, you can look at extraction of meaning from text, though I do not know how successful it might be.

Answer (score 4):

apparently the NLTK, a python natural language processing library, has one:

http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/

Probably worth having a look at it.